# Recursion of a function till we find a output of recursion is equal to some list

Tags: python, list

I have two integer lists say list_a and list_b
I have a function say func(), and func(list_a) would produce n lists say:

```
list_a_1   list_a_2  list_a_3   list_a_4 ........... list_a_n
```

I have to run func() on all lists as produced above until I find one of those lists = list_b.

So below could be the possible representation of how the list grows:

```
                                 list_a

============================================================================

list_a_1   list_a_2  list_a_3   list_a_4 ........... list_a_n    LEVEL 1

============================================================================

list_a_1_1.... list_a_1_n    list_a_2_1... list_a_2_n.....      LEVEL 2

============================================================================
```

Suppose say we find list_a_1_n == list_b, then stop the function and return the LEVEL , which in our case is 2 (Level2).

I am not being able to do it :(

How to do it in Python?

**EDIT**

Please note, this is not a homework question.

I am trying to find Cyclic Kendal Tau distance between two inputs as I think I found a solution in terms of algorithm for [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/what-is-the-best-approach-algorithm-to-find-cyclic-kendal-tau-distance?noredirect=1#comment66827_27938) question. I want to check whether my algorithm is correct.

Comment: whats the logic behind your program ? and what you try ?

Comment: @MightyPork definitely not. I am trying to solve [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27938/what-is-the-best-approach-algorithm-to-find-cyclic-kendal-tau-distance?noredirect=1#comment66827_27938). Looks like I found a way, but I want to check whether my algorithm is correct.

Comment: @Kasra Trying to find **Cyclic Kendal Tau distance** between two inputs.

Comment: @AnakataAndrese you need to add it to your question with an example and desire output ! as more you explain about your problem as you get more complete answer !

Comment: @Kasra Thanks a lot for the tip. Yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like you're interested in a breadth first search.

```
def func(l):
    return [l_1, l_2, l_3, ...]

def work(start, goal):
    queue = collections.deque([(start, 0)])

    while queue:
        element, level = queue.popleft()
        if element == goal:
            return level
        for new_list in func(element)
            queue.append((new_list, level + 1))
```

Comment: Somewhat understood the flow. But what is the initial value of query here?

Comment: goal in my case(as per question) is list_b. But query is list_a?? is that what you are saying @BillLynch?

Comment: So this is a typical breadth first search implementation. Each element in the deque (which is a good container to use as a queue), is the tuple `(list, level)`. So, we initialize the queue to have the initial element which we know is at level 0. We then start our loop. We pop the queue, and look to see if the top of the queue has the element we are looking for. If it doesn't then we push onto the bottom of the queue all of the elements that we would make via the transformation in the question.

Comment: Yeah. `list_a` and `list_b` are fairly terrible names because they don't have a meaning. So `list_a` is the start value and `list_b` is the goal value.

Comment: Perfection at its best. Thanks a lot for such a wonderful explanation. It works perfect for small space. But slows down for my test matrix where list_a and list_b (start and goal) are of size say 10. :(

Comment: @AnakataAndrese: So the next step in this process would be two steps: __1.__ Store in a `set` all of the elements that you have seen before. So you don't reiterate over them. Then __2__, score the lists that you have computed for how close it is to the goal. Then, instead of a deque, use a min heap so that you always pop the next one closest to the goal.

Comment: V_V Greek and Latin for me.  :(

Comment: So the above implements a breadth-first search. What I was describing in that comment is called a [best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search). In implementing a best-first search, we often use a min-heap, which you can read about [here](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~ananth/CptS223/Lectures/heaps.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am happpy that my algorithm gives results. :) I will try to read them up and implement. Will ask if I am stuck with something.

Answer (score -1):

There are many unknowns. For example, what does func() exactly generate? What is the content of the list? Is a simple == enough to check the equality of the lists, etc.

Anyway, with the provided information, here is a possible solution:

```
def getMatchingLevel(list_a, list_b, level=0):

    if list_a == list_b:
        return level

    #generate the list
    list_of_lists = func(list_a) #this is the func() mentioned in your question

    #for breadth first search
    for elist in list_of_lists:
        if elist == list_b:
            return level+1

    #no match in the breadth - go deep
    for elist in list_of_lists:
        result = getMatchingList(elist, list_b, level+1)
        if result:
            return result
    return None
```

EDIT: to include the logic to return the level instead of the matching list itself.

Comment: The func() is as per [here](http://pastebin.com/a7RFZTeM). But your psuedocode does not return the level. Right?

Comment: This is a depth first search. So if the match is `list_a_2_1`, you will never find it. (Unless getMatchingList eventually returns an empty list... Which I don't think is the case). If that assumption is true, your code could be rewritten as: https://gist.github.com/sharth/5c35d7b2b0be3910a66c

Comment: Here, works fine if size of list_a and list_b are small. Else (size =10) throws the "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp".